# Return all the fields from a class

Tags: c#, reflection

I am attempting to cycle through the Fields in my class, place the fields of a certain type into a list and then return that list. I know I am missing some key component but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. This is what I have so far:

`...`

I need to return a list of the actual fields as pointers, not a copy of the data.  Any help in getting this to work would be appreciated.

I removed the above code (you should still be able to see it in the history) because it was confusing.  This is the updated code (with some extra stuff removed) that works thanks to the answer from competent_tech:

```
string prop1;
BaseClass prop2;
SubClass prop3;
SubClass prop4;

public List<BaseClass> GetData()
{
    List<BaseClass> DataList = new List<BaseClass>();

    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo thisInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var tempPropery = thisInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        if (tempPropery.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)) || tempPropery.GetType().Equals(typeof(BaseClass)))
        {
            DataList.Add((BaseClass)tempPropery);
        };
    }

    return DataList;
}
```

The above code will allow you to get all the properties of a specific base type from your class and return them in a list. So the above code would return prop2 - prop4.

Comment: I would use a `Dictionary<string,PrimaryAbility>` instead. Then you could get `STR` in this way: `var str = AllAbilities["STR"];`. Needing reflection   often  indicates that you should refactor your code.

Comment: I am looking for an easy (yet complicated at the start) way to return all the Abilities (and other classes use the same structure) rather than having to add in an extra line of code every time I add something new in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this through reflection.

```
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo oProperty in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
}
```

There are numerous ways that you can use this information once you have it or filter the properties (for example, by adding an attribute to the properties that you want to collect).

You can get more information [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx).

Note that this code specifically references properties, but there are equivalent methods for retrieving fields ([GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx)) and all members ([GetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424c79hc.aspx)).

Once you have the PropertyInfo, you can call the GetValue method:

```
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo oProperty in this.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            Console.WriteLine(oProperty.Name + " = " + oProperty.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
        }
```

Alternatively, if you are looking at both fields and properties:

```
        foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo oMember in this.GetType().GetMembers())
        {
            switch (oMember.MemberType)
            {
                case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field:
                    var oField = (System.Reflection.FieldInfo)oMember;
                    Console.WriteLine(oField.Name + " = " + oField.GetValue(this).ToString());
                    break;

                case System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property:
                    var oProperty = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)oMember;
                    Console.WriteLine(oProperty.Name + " = " + oProperty.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I need further explanation on how to use this. This is basically the same thing as my line: `var tempList = this.GetType().GetMembers();` - I don't know how to extract the field once I have the info.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the answer to show retrieval of the name and value in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in Dictionary. For every property only set/get value from dictionary.
Something like this:

```
public class MyData {
    private Dictionary<string, object> myData;
    public MyData {
        this.myData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public decimal LastVersion { get { return (decimal)this.myData["LastVersion"]; } private set { this.myData["LastVersion"] = value; } }

    public PrimaryAbility STR { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["STR"]; } private set { this.myData["STR"] = value; } }
    public PrimaryAbility DEX { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["DEX"]; } private set { this.myData["DEX"] = value; } }
    public PrimaryAbility CON { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["CON"]; } private set { this.myData["CON"] = value; } }
    public PrimaryAbility INT { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["INT"]; } private set { this.myData["INT"] = value; } }
    public PrimaryAbility WIS { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["WIS"]; } private set { this.myData["WIS"] = value; } }
    public PrimaryAbility CHA { get { return (PrimaryAbility)this.myData["CHA"]; } private set { this.myData["CHA"] = value; } }

    public DerivedAbility HP { get { return (DerivedAbility)this.myData["HP"]; } private set { this.myData["HP"] = value; } }
    public DerivedAbility MP { get { return (DerivedAbility)this.myData["MP"]; } private set { this.myData["MP"] = value; } }
    public DerivedAbility SP { get { return (DerivedAbility)this.myData["SP"]; } private set { this.myData["SP"] = value; } }
    public DerivedAbility AC { get { return (DerivedAbility)this.myData["AC"]; } private set { this.myData["AC"] = value; } }
}
```

Some day I found this: "Enum.GetValues(typeof(TvStations))", maybe you should search some like this.