# Is it possible to iterate through variables in a module?

Tags: c#, vb.net

A development/testing form contains a DataGridView that is loaded with the name and value of every variable in a global module.  The downside is that adding or removing a variable requires a corresponding change to the form.  Is there a way to iterate through the variables defined in a module class, getting their names and values?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "module class". Modules are modules and classes are classes. You could say that modules are classes too, if you're talking about what happens to them after compilation. The C# equivalent of a module is a static class, i.e. a class for which all members must be static. That's why module members behave like `Shared` members in VB. At the language level though, modules are their own thing, with the concept retained from VB6.

Comment: As for your question, you should look into Reflection and, in particular, the `Type.GetFields` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return all the fields from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410197/return-all-the-fields-from-a-class)

Comment: @madreflection, one point to note is that, as you can't have an instance of a module, you can't call `Me.GetType()` or `someInstance.GetType()`. To get a `Type` object for a module, you must use `GetType(MyModule)`, where `MyModule` is the actual data type and not a reference to an instance of that type. In that case, `GetType` is the VB keyword and not the `GetType` method of the current object.

Comment: Got it, and it works!  Many thanks to you both!!  I'll answer with my code, for the record.

Answer (score 1):

The vb.net code that works (amended):

```
    Try
        With dgvGlobalVariables.Rows
            For Each oMember As MemberInfo In GetType(modGlobal).GetRuntimeFields
                Dim oField As FieldInfo = CType(oMember, FieldInfo)
                Try
                    Dim sValue As String = oField.GetValue(oField).ToString
                    .Add(oField.Name, sValue)

                Catch ex As Exception
                    .Add(oField.Name)
                End Try
            Next
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        With System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
            P_WriteErrorToLog(ex.ToString, .ReflectedType.Name & "." & .Name)
        End With
    End Try
```